# Trouble inserting values into SQL table, values get mistaken for columns

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, ado.net

I keep getting an exception that reads:

> "Invalid Column Name, 'IBM'."

The error is happening at: `"' + @ticker + '"` even though `@ticker` is declared in `VALUES`. I suspect the error could be taking place at some other point in the query, but I'm pretty new to SQL/T-SQL, so I'm not sure how to figure out where.

```cs
private string InsertRecord(Indicator indicator)
{
    try
    {
        if (!CheckIfColumnExists(indicator.GetType().Name))
        {
            AddColumn(indicator.GetType().Name, SqlDbType.Real);
        }

        const string query = @"
        DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
        INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + '(
        ' + QUOTENAME(@indicator) + ', date, ticker)  
        VALUES(' + @indicatorValue + ', ' + @date + ', ' + @ticker + ') 
        ';

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
        ";

        //checking if the record is already there
        if (!CheckIfRecordExists(indicator))
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionstring))
            {



                conn.Open();


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query , conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", tableName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@indicator", indicator.GetType().Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@indicatorValue", indicator.Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", indicator.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticker", indicator.Ticker);
                var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();




                return "New Record Inserted";


            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Record Already Exists";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Failure Inserting New Record";
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm accepting CharlieFace's answer, because it avoids breaches via SQL Injection, and explains the necessity for sp_executesql.

Comment: Also, you dont add ticks to parameter placeholders (`'@placeholder'`).  In general rather than creating elaborate machines - such as code to insert into any table -, start with simple, straight forward  code until you have a few years experience

Comment: @YongShun `Indicator` is a class that extends multiple subclasses, so `indicator.GetType().Name` will change based on what the Indicator is declared as, in this case the string reads "SMA". Also, thank you for the tips, I guess I'll just use concatenation.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Okay, thanks I'll take them out. Thank you for the advice as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in the parameters which contain data (as opposed to column and table names) all the way to `sp_executesql`

```sql
        const string query = @"
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + '(
  ' + QUOTENAME(@indicator) + ', date, ticker)  
VALUES(@indicatorValue, @date, @ticker) 
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@indicatorValue nvarchar(100), @date date, @ticker nvarchar(100)',
  @indicatorValue,
  @date,
  @ticker;
";
```

You should also pass the parameters as their real values (date, int) rather than `ToString`. Also declare the parameter types and lengths explicitly

```cs
// table and column name should be NVARCHAR(128)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tableName", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 128).Value = tableName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@indicator", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 128).Value = indicator.GetType().Name;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@indicatorValue", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 100).Value = indicator.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = indicator.Date;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ticker", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 100).Value = indicator.Ticker;
```

Comment: there was a small syntactical error at : `N'@indicatorValue nvarchar(100), @date date, @ticker nvarchar(100);,`, it should be: `N'@indicatorValue nvarchar(100), @date date, @ticker nvarchar(100)',`

Answer (score 1):

**Concerns**

1. You can't use parameters to append values for table name and column name. Instead, **string concatenation** is needed although this will **lead to an open SQL Injection attack** (Example: [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)). Hence, ensure that you have **done enough validation** for the `tableName` or the string concatenation part.
2. You don't need to append single quotes `'` for the parameters in the query. This will be done automatically when `SQLCommand` appends the `SQLParameter` value to query according to the parameter type.
3. I don't see there is a need to use `EXEC sp_executesql`. While you can just straight-way execute the `INSERT` query.
4. In StackOverflow community, normally would be suggested to use `SqlCommand.Add("@Name", SqlDbType).Value` and specify the parameter type instead of `SqlCommand.AddWithValue()`. Refer to [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://bobby-tables.com/).

In conclusion, your `SqlCommand` should be as:

```cs
string query = @"
    INSERT INTO " + tableName + 
    "(" + indicator.GetType().Name + ", date, ticker)" +
    " VALUES (@indicatorValue, @date, @ticker)"; 

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query , conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@indicatorValue", SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = indicator.Value.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = indicator.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ticker", SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = indicator.Ticker;
```

Comment: There *is* a reason to use `sp_executesql`: in order to use `QUOTENAME`. You are not using it, and therefore could have an injection problem. Also you should pass parameter lengths, not just types. And the parameter values still have `ToString()` which they should not